# CSS class is picked up where it's not set

Tags: css

This class makes a table with alternating row color in pairs (two gray, two white, etc):

```
.table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1), tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

The problem is that it affects tables without `class="table-striped-two-rows"` too.

How can I contain the styling to just the tables with the class?

Comment: `.table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1), .table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the ancestor also for the `4n + 2` rows in order to limit the scope of the selector

```
.table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1), 
.table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> .table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1), tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2)

You neglected to make the table class part of the second part of the selector:

```
.table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1),
.table-striped-two-rows tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2)
```